# How to show allowBlank error only on form submission?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a form with textfield and textareafield, I have provided allowBlank: false to both the columns, but I need to show Red error design and blank error only on form submission not before that. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Form fields have two boolean configs, `validateOnBlur` and `validateOnChange`. If you set these to `false`, fields won't be validated during user input. In this case you have add a code for example to your submit button, to check for validation errors. `Ext.form.Basic` has `isValid` and `hasInvalidField` methods that you can call, the first marks validation errors, the second does not.

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome. Please consider accepting my answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: Never mind, happy coding!

Comment: var tpl = but.up('panel').getDockedItems('[refId=bottomDock]')[0].query('[itemId=errorListContainer]')[0]; this line is giving error when trying to close the error container. Any idea about this? @PeterKoltai

Answer (score 0):

@Peter Koltai has the correct answer for classic.

For modern you should use:

```
    validateTextfield(field) {
        test...
        if(!valid){
            field.setErrorMessage('bad decision');
        }
    },
    onBeforeSubmit() {
        const form = this.getView(),
            values = form.getValues(),
            isTextFieldValid = this.validateTextfield(values.fromTextField);
        return isTextFieldValid;
    }
    onSubmit() {
        const isValid = this.onBeforeSubmit();

        if(!isValid) return;

        doMySubmission();
    }
```

Comment: can you please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70420646/13672765

Comment: I need more information for the given question. Are you using my approach? Sounds like you are validating the wrong field on `change event`.