# How to disable invalid mark shown on other field when in one field something is entered?

Tags: extjs

I have a form where i have a textfield named Title and one textareafield named Content, something weird is happening, like when I click on Title and enter something then automatically the Content field throws validation error, how to rectify this? I have tried Change event but that throws another error container error.

Comment: could you setup a fiddle, showing the error. It sounds like you are validating the wrong field (if you listen to all fields change events and validate, this might happen)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.